# I am getting an error while I'm trying to create a project in Azure Language studio custom question answering

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, language-studio

I am getting an error while I'm trying to create a project in Azure Language studio custom question answering.

Failed to open project A server error occurred while trying to open your project. Please refresh and try again.Azure language customquestionanswering

https://language.cognitive.azure.com/questionAnswering/

**Failed to open project**:

[image]

**Import project failed**:

[image]

I tried to create project with both option of selecting the language for projects. - Failed
Tried to import project - Failed

Resource type: Language
Location: Southeastasia
Price tier: Standard (S)

Answer (score 1):

The answer form [Venkatesan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76090275/21052833) is good enough, but in case the error persists, try this.

After assigned the roles, I was still getting the error, and noticed that when creating a new resource for the [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/custom/quickstart?pivots=language-studio) example, I was getting:

> The portal cannot access your storage account, please enable CORS policies on your storage account.

So I went to my Storage Resource CORS policies and added

- Allowed origins: *
- Allowed methods: all
- Allowed headers: *
- Exposed headers: *
- Max age: 120

This fixed the issue for me.

More about CORS [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services).

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I tried to import the project with xlsx and got the same error:

[image]

To import a project in Azure Language Service, the following roles are required:

1. **Owner**(Full control to access the services)
2. **Contributor**: (Create,update, read access to the services)
3. **Reader**: (Only can view)

I assigned **`contributor`** role to the user.

**Role:**

[image]

**Studio:**

After assigning **`Contributor`** role to the user, I can able to import the project successfully into language studio.

[image]

**Reference:**
[Create, test, and deploy your question answering project - Azure Cognitive Services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/question-answering/how-to/create-test-deploy)